# What is the opposite of the word "confirm"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking at the following usage in particular: "I want to confirm this theory."

Comment: It depends on: in which sense of the word, and in what context, you want to use the sentence. Possible antonyms: refute, deny and other words.

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/confirm

Comment: in the sense of confirming "are you sure?", a good reverse is I think "cancel". replacing the language "not if confirmed" to "if not confirmed" to "if cancelled" works well.

Answer (score 30):

I prefer to use the word **[refute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refute)** in such a circumstance.

> 1. to prove wrong by argument or evidence : show to be false or erroneous
> 2. to deny the truth or accuracy of

Answer (score 11):

[Disconfirm](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disconfirm):

> The empirical data obtained in a test—or, as we shall prefer to say, the observation sentences describing those data—may then either *confirm* or *disconfirm* the given hypothesis, or they may be neutral with respect to it.

[Disprove](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disprove):

> By careful observation, I have *disproved* that the earth orbits the sun.

Comment: *Disconfirm* [is in MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disconfirm) but it's horrible.

Comment: To me, "disconfirm" means "fail to confirm". That is a much weaker claim than "refute".

Comment: Upvote for 'disprove'. Meaning "prove falsehood of the claim". "Refute" is good too, but you  usually refute a claim using a pre-existing proof of its falsehood. You disprove it by taking it apart and showing how it's wrong.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I agree that it sounds like a non-word. But it's reasonably popular as per Google Books especially in science and philosophy. While it initially appeared to be a word inevitably - as in the example in my answer - paired with _confirm_, this isn't really the case either. _Disprove_ is, as expected, far more popular.

Answer (score 8):

You might want something like *disprove*, *invalidate*, or *deny*, no?

Comment: Add _refute_ and I think you got them all.

Comment: I don't think someone would normally say, "I deny this theory" or "This experiment will deny your theory." I agree taht "disprove" and "refute" would be common words for that idea.

Comment: Some academics, in a moment of passionate emotion, might use something like _destroy_: "I want to _destroy_ this theory!" (I'm not saying that's a good choice for an antonym, mind you, I'm just saying such a would could be used in that capacity.)

Comment: What about *debunk*? The [Merriam-Webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debunk) even has this sample sentence: *The results of the study debunk his theory.*

Comment: @JLG Oh yes, ***debunk***!, Sure.

Comment: Debunk is a little informal, and probably inappropriate for the questioner's intended setting.  On the other hand, if it's intended for a popular general-circulation magazine, "debunk" is perfect.

Answer (score 7):

How about this...?

[Rebut](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rebut)

> To deny the truth of something, especially by presenting arguments
>   that disprove it.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [reject](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reject) or [refute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refute).

Answer (score 3):

What about:

[Debunk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/debunk)

> To discredit, or expose to ridicule the falsehood or the exaggerated
>   claims of something

Comment: This is too informal to be used in an academic paper, which it most likely where the questioner has in mind to use it.

Comment: Seriously?  This post is months old...

Comment: @user23794 This is not a forum, questions, answers and comments are believed to have value for the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Denounce** might be an option, but that usually refers to a commonly held belief being disproved. It also suggests its subject is non-scientific.

The other users suggested **disprove** and **refute** (which I like), which apply well in scientific experiments. More specifically, *refute* suggests you disproving a previously held belief, while *disprove* suggests your results turning out against a certain hypothesis or outcome.

In your example: "By careful observation, I have **__** that the Earth orbits the sun.", I would probably go with *disprove* myself.

Definitions:

> - *disprove* — to prove that something is false
> - *refute* — to prove a statement or theory is wrong; disprove
> - *denounce* — publicly declare to be wrong; inform against