# Antonym of "confirm" that refers to facts and not opinion

Tags: antonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the opposite of the word confirm?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66576/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-word-confirm)

In some cases, the antonym of *confirm* would be *deny*.

> I **confirm** that the rumors are true.
>
> I **deny** that the rumors are true.

However, in a scientific sense, that doesn't make sense to me.

> By careful observation, I have **confirmed** that the earth orbits the sun.
>
> By careful observation, I have **denied** that the earth orbits the sun.

The use of *deny* here seems to imply that I'm talking about my opinion on the subject, as opposed to me having established a scientific fact.